# Clases que son fuente de eventos para listeners de diferentes interfaces

Tags: java, eventos

Hablando de eventos personalizados por el usuario.
En el caso de que una clase sea fuente de eventos para listeners que implementan diferentes interfaces ¿Creo una lista de listeners y en el bucle de distribución de eventos discrimino a la interface que quiero mandarle el evento (mediante instanceof), o por el contrario creo varias listas, una para cada tipo de listener? 
Gracias

Comment: Podrias agregar el codigo para poder ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 0):

Supongamos una clase `MiClase` cuyos objetos pueden lanzar dos tipos de eventos: `Evento1` y `Evento2`.

Supongamos también que tenemos un interfaz `Evento1Listener` y otra interfaz `Evento2Listener`, que tengan definidos los métodos `cuandoEvento1` y `cuandoEvento2`, respectivamente.

Ahora imagina que tengo dos instancias `MiClase`, y una instancia de una clase que cumple ambas interfaces, pero que quiero que escuche los eventos `Evento1` de una de las instancias de `MiClase` y los eventos Evento2 de la otra instancia:

```
class MiListener implements Evento1Listener, Evento2Listener { 

    void cuandoEvento1(Evento1 e) {
        ...
    }
    void cuandoEvento2(Evento2 e) {
        ...
    }

}


MiClase obj1= new MiClase();
MiClase obj2= new MiClase();
MiListener l= new MiListener();

obj1.addEvento1Listener(l);
obj2.addEvento2Listener(l);
```

Como puedes ver, el mirar qué interfaz implementa no ayuda en nada, debes guardar los listeners en diferentes colas (l podría estar en las dos).
Es algo habitual que una clase implemente más de una interfaz: cuando diseñas una UI con Swing, el contenedor suele escuchar los eventos de los elementos contenidos para poder actual sobre otros.

Comment: Entiendo pues que la opción correcta es una lista por cada listener.

Muchas gracias